# How do I show a JavaFX webview when I click on a Menu item?

Tags: java, javafx

In my application I want the user user to be able to click on a menu item and have a new window appear. However, when I run my code it says that you can open a new window from a menu item. So my question is,is there another work around or another simpler way for me to accomplish my goal. Thanks for your help.

P.S --> I had posted a similar question earlier, but had made a mistake in copying the correct code I had. This is the correct error and code I get.

**Code:**

```
    /**
 * When the Logger menu item is clicked, then it will execute and make a new window
 * @param actionEvent
 * @throws Exception
 */
public void clickedLoggerMenu(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws Exception {
    //The name of the controller
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/viewer_logger.fxml"));
    Parent home_page = (Parent) loader.load();

    LoggerController logController = loader.getController();

    //this sets the scene
        Scene home_page_scene = new Scene(home_page, 650, 580);
        Stage app_stage = (Stage) ((Node) actionEvent.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        app_stage.setScene(home_page_scene);
        app_stage.show();

}
```

**Exception:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.controls@10.0.1/javafx.scene.control.MenuItem cannot be cast to javafx.graphics@10.0.1/javafx.scene.Node
    at controller.SubmitController.clickedLoggerMenu(SubmitController.java:99)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in how you are trying to create the `Stage`:

```
Stage app_stage = (Stage) ((Node) actionEvent.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
```

You are trying to cast the `MenuItem` to a `Node` and that is not how it works.

You also need to create a new `Stage` anyway, so do not try to get the original `Window`.

```
Stage app_stage = new Stage()
```

Then build the `Scene` from there.

**Side Note:** I recommend reading some good JavaFX tutorials to learn the basics.